# Google Charts throws "cannot read property '1' of undefined" when creating a view

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am working with google charts and would like to create a line chart where not all colums from the underlying `data` is visible. I found here - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView that DataViewClass should be a good solution for it and tried to implement it as below. Unfortunately when I try to generate the chart I am getting "cannot read property '1' of undefined" error but no errors in the console.

Has anyone came across this? Any ideas for the solution?

best,

Adam

```
function testersBreakdown (testType, app){


// Data for the graph - need to be replaced by a correct query to backend
// TO DO: Format data and generate graphs
var data;

data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'Test Cycle');
data.addColumn('number', 'Total');
data.addColumn('number', 'F2F');
data.addColumn('number', 'Scalable In the Office');
data.addColumn('number', 'Remote Testing');
    data.addRows([
    [1, 10, 3, 4, 3],
    [2, 11, 4, 4, 3],
    [3, 15, 3, 9, 3],
    [4, 20, 3, 9, 8],
    [5, 45, 30, 14, 1]

    ]);

var options = {
    width: '100%',
    height: 600,

    hAxis: {
      title: 'Test Cycle'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Responses'
    },
    colors: ['#a52714', '#097138', 'black', 'blue'],
    animation: {
        duration: 300,
        startup: true,
    },
   };

// Intermediate object to control views based on dropdown
// TO DO: Determine what to show based on the testType dropdown selected
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

    view.setColumns(['Test Cycle','Total' ]); //here you set the columns you want to display
    //Visualization Go draw!

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('testTypeChart'));
  chart.draw(view, options);
```

};

Comment: OK, it seems that the animation parameter in options was causing an error. After commenting it out, everything works fine. Any ideas why that is?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a bug when using animations with a dataView (see [this](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/1876) issue for more info regarding the bug). 
 To solve this try loading the release candidate from google instead of the stable`google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});` with `google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["corechart"]});`.

<s>Check here for more info about using release candidates.</s>
I've got to little repuptation to post more than 2 links, so if you go to the google developers page (that you linked to) and then navigate to "Google Chart News" and scroll to the bottom-ish you can find more info about this.

I also tried it in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atgb7pd9/) and it works like a charm.
Hope it helped!
Henrik

Comment: [Release Process](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes#ReleaseProcess)
Here's the link to the releaseprocess I wrote about, info about the latest release candidate can be found here: [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!searchin/google-visualization-api/release$20candidate%7Csort:date/google-visualization-api/XxP1zYbWQRE/sQd6IHwtnSgJ)